# Android MVP pattern integrating third party SDKs

Tags: android, architecture, sdk, mvp

I am learning MVP pattern by following Google sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp.
Now I need to integrate third party SDK like Gigya for my app login. To initialize Gigya I need to write 
`GSAPI.getInstance().initialize(getActivity(), API_Key);`. So where I am suppose to write this, that is in Fragment or Presenter. If in presenter then is it good approach to use activity context in presenter?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that the presenter should have no concept of the Android Context (or any other Android classes). By completely separating your Presenter code from the Android system code you are able to test it on the JVM without the complication of mocking system components.

You have two ways:

1. Use Dagger
2. Or create a repository interface

I have never done this so i cannot explain it in detail.Search the net 
for my two suggested ways,Hope it helps.